# Правильное место для Scanner close()

Tags: java

Есть следующий код:

```
public class test {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static String line = scanner.nextLine();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scanner.close();  
    }
}
```

Вопрос следующий: почему невозможно поставить `close()` (закрыть Scanner) сразу после считывания в переменную? Почему необходимо закрывать сканнер только в методе main?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для этого статическую инициализацию и поле Scanner уберите вообще

```
public class test {
    private static String line;

    static {
      try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        line = scanner.nextLine();
      }
    }
}
```

или статическую функцию

```
public class test {
    private static String line = getLine();

    private static String getLine() {
      try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        return scanner.nextLine();
      }
    }
}
```

В данных примерах используется оператор [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html),  который сам закроет сканер при выходе из блока try

Comment: то есть закрывать сканнер не обязательно?

Comment: В данном коде используется оператор [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html), который сам закроет сканер